# jscript document.getElementsByName in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, dom

which is similar in c# ?

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
var HTML = e.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please provide more info on your scenario. What's the input and what are you trying to get out of it?

Answer (score 2):

Recursive FindControl method:

```
    private Control RecursiveControlFind(Control parent, string controlID)
    {
        Control child = parent.FindControl(controlID);
        if (child == null)
        {
            if (parent.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Control nestedControl in parent.Controls)
                {
                    child = RecursiveControlFind(nestedControl, controlID);
                    if (child != null)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Control.FindControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) but it isn't recursive.